# RXJS6 - return an Observable from a Promise function which returns an Observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, es6-promise

I have a method `getData` which returns an `Observable<SupportingDocument>`.
(*code and return value can't be changed as it's an external API*).

```
  getData(): Observable<SupportingDocument> {
    return of(new SupportingDocument());
  }
```

When a user clicks a button , we actually show him a Modal page . When that modal is closed ( Promise api) - we should call `getData()` and return the value :

```
  public dialogShow(): Promise<Observable<SupportingDocument>> {
    return Promise.resolve(1).then(() => { //modal was closed
      return this.getData();
    })
  }
```

At the end , I should provide a method `show()` which should return the value(and errors) that returned from  `return this.getData();` ( *shows()'s return value doesn't have to be an Observable  , it can be a promise too*).

So I did this :

```
  public show(): Observable<SupportingDocument> {
    return new Observable<SupportingDocument>((obs) => {
      this.dialogShow().then((res: Observable<SupportingDocument>) => obs.next(res), (res) => obs.error(res));
    })
  }
```

**Complete code :**

```
//user starts here
public show(): Observable<SupportingDocument> {
    return new Observable<SupportingDocument>((obs) => {
      this.dialogShow().then((res: Observable<SupportingDocument>) => obs.next(res), (res) => obs.error(res));
    })
  }



  public dialogShow(): Promise<Observable<SupportingDocument>> {
    return Promise.resolve(1).then(() => {
      return this.getData();
    })
  }


  getData(): Observable<SupportingDocument> {
    return of(new SupportingDocument());

  }
```

**Question**

I think I've over-complicated  such a simple task. More - I really don't like the `new Observable` constructor approach.

Can this problem be solved without using the observable constructor ( including error handling) solution ?

[**Full demo code**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4kvfxo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Don't use the `Observable` constructor. There are built-in methods to convert from and to promises, use them.

Comment: @Bergi After changing , it doesn't return the right result...https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4kvfxo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't just wrap the `Promise` into an `Observable` *(so that you can use all the operators an `Observable` can provide)*, and then use a `switchMap()`?

```
public dialogShow(): Observable<SupportingDocument> {
    return from(Promise.resolve(1)).pipe(switchMap(() => this.getData()));
}
```

Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbzl7v?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I should've seen it :) Thanks